# How do I install Stage and stage_ros?

Tags: ros, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a bit new on ROS and I'm having some difficulties installing Stage on my computer. I'm trying to install this package http://wiki.ros.org/stage and http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros. I git cloned stage_ros into my catkin_ws and when I tried to catkin_make it I was missing Stage. The problem that I'm having is to know where and how to install Stage. After that I'd like to implement joystick control but I want to get this sorted out first.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

This is the error that I get when I try to catkin_make:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'stage_ros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(stage_ros)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
statusFLTK_LIBRARIES=fltk_imagesfltk_formsfltk_gl/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.sofltk/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
statusFLTK_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/fltk/usr/include
statusFLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include
-- checking for module 'stage'
--   package 'stage' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find Stage (missing: Stage_LIBRARIES Stage_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  stage_ros/cmake/StageConfig.cmake:23 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  stage_ros/CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/onr/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/onr/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 which I think would work for the apt-get install but I just need to know that right commands. What I've been doing is following this tutorial to install Player/Stage http://rtv.github.io/Stage/install.html and this one as well [http://ranger.uta.edu/~gianluca/astra/projects/robotsimulation/Robotic%20Simulation%20Guide.pdf](http://ranger.uta.edu/%7Egianluca/astra/projects/robotsimulation/Robotic%20Simulation%20Guide.pdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214157/how-do-i-install-stage-and-stage_ros?/) by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because `stage` is what we call a non-catkin third party package you cannot build it in the same workspace as stage_ros using just `catkin_make`. `catkin_make` assumes that all packages in the workspace are catkin packages. In fact I would have expected that it gave you an error message to the effect. You'll have to give us more information about where you downloaded the two packages to and what commands you ran and where.

Also if you're on Ubuntu (you didn't mention your system type) you can just apt-get install them...

If you don't have any other ROS stuff installed on your system then you'll more that just `stage` and `stage_ros` because `stage_ros` uses lots of other ROS packages too.

EDIT:

You can just install it from apt-get then, `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-stage-ros`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
Update any roslaunch files to `<node pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros"` . See:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/192600/stage-not-working/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/200779/question-about-tutorial-introduction-to-stage-controllers-stageros-problem/